# Azure cosmos db geographical data query inconsistency

Tags: azure, gis, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

With a cosmos DB geospatial configuration to geography and executing following queries I get (what seem to me) inconsistent results:

[image: Point is inside if bottom bound is -9]
[image: Point is outside if bottom bound is -10]

When changing the geospatial configuration to geometry, the result are as expected. So I assume there is some GIS principle I overlooked? We also tried similar queries in SQL server and there the results are as expected.

Query for reference:

```
SELECT ST_WITHIN({'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [
            7.75,
            45.12
        ]},
    {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[
    [30.80, 59.40],
    [-10, 59.40],
    [-10, 43.35],
    [30.80, 43.35],
    [30.80, 59.40]
]]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will not produce the same results because Geography plots over the Earth and Geometry is an flat plane. When using Geometry mode you need to define a bounding box as this plane is infinite. Please see [Geometry data indexing examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-geospatial-index#geometry-data-indexing-examples) for more details.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I don't see how this would impact the ST_WITHIN  function, since both points (projected or not) would be within the given range?

Comment: That's my point. They are not, try plotting them here, https://sooeet.com/maps/great-circle-mapper.php